# How do I use debugbar for JSON answer using Symfony 1 (with no views)

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I would like to use the symfony debugbar to monitor the database queries when I render json answer without a view.

If I want to see the queries:

- either I activate the mysql log and monitor it
- or I remove the `return renderJSON()` and
  regarding the action I create an empty template to make the debugbar
  visible

Is there any easier way to make the queries visible?

Answer (score 1):

Queries will be logged to the log file related to app / environment you're working in:

`{project_root}/log/...`

So if you're testing via `frontend_dev.php` log file will be:

`{project_root}/log/frontend_dev.log`

Logging needs to be enabled in the `settings.yml` file for the app you're working in.

In Linux/Mac you can use `tail` to watch the log in real time:

`tail -f log/frontend_dev.log` (assuming you're in project root)

`ctrl + c` / `cmd + c` to stop tailing the log.

More on logging here:

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/16-Application-Management-Tools

Comment: good point, thanks! But it doesn't really different from that I monitor the mysql log itself. Seeing them directly on the UI would be helpful.